# Macvim space indent using Markdown

Tags: vim, macvim

I am editing Markdown using Macvim and may I know is there anyway that I can set it, so that whenever I enter, the space indent on the previous line is maintain. I don't want to use TAB for every single line. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling the `autoindent` option:

```
:set autoindent
```

or:

```
:set ai
```

Explanation from Vim manual:

```
'autoindent' 'ai'   boolean (default off)
        local to buffer
Copy indent from current line when starting a new line (typing <CR>
in Insert mode or when using the "o" or "O" command).
```